# What is the order of the pole of $\frac{\mathrm{Log}(z)}{(z-1)^3}$ at $z=1$?

Tags: complex-analysis

I read somewhere that the series for the principal branch of $$\mathrm{Log}(z) = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^{(n+1)}(z-1)^n}{n}$$
If this is true does it means that the order of the pole is equal to $2$ at $z=1$?
Or is it wrong, which in case how do I approach this problem?

Comment: That's correct, $\mathrm{Log}(z)$ vanishes to order $1$ at $z=1$, so the pole has order $2$.

Comment: then just to be thorough how to show that $Log(z)$ vanishes to order $1$ at $z=1$. I mean how to show that the series of it is what was stated. do I just show the Taylor series around $1$

Comment: Another way is to note that $\mathrm{Log}(1)=0$ and $\frac{d}{dz}\mathrm{Log}(z)=\frac{1}{z}$, which is non-zero at $z=1$.

Answer (score 1):

For the principal branch of $\log z $ : Let $z+1+y.$ Then for $0<|y|<1$ we have $$(z-1)^{-3}\log z=y^{-3}\log (1+y)=y^{-3}\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}y^n/n=  y^{-2}+y^{-1}/2+\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}y^n/(n+3).$$ So,as you said, the order of the pole at $z=1$ is $2.$